mediaRecorder: removing a chunk before building the Blob does not provide the expected results
The purpose of the test code in the snippet is to build a speech interactively, chunk by chunk.
If you don't like the last recorded chunk, you can simply remove it from the chunks array (chunks.pop()) and keep recording new chunks.
Then you can build the blob from the resulting chunks array.
The problem is that even when a chunk is removed, it leaves a 'silence' in the final audio file that lasts for the entire duration of the removed chunk.
It seems that the chunks have some sort of timestamp and are not simply concatenated.
How can I achieve my goal? Thank you.
PS: the snippet does not work from inside stackoverflow because there is no authorization to record audio.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MediaRecorder Chunks Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="startRecord">Start Recording</button>
    <button id="pauseRecord" disabled>Pause Recording</button>
    <button id="stopRecord" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
    <button id="playRecording" disabled>Play Recording</button>
    <button id="popChunk" disabled>Pop Last Chunk</button>

    <audio id="audioPlayback" controls></audio>

    <script>
        let mediaRecorder;
        let chunks = [];
        let audioURL;
        let recording = false;

        document.getElementById('startRecord').addEventListener('click', startRecording);
        document.getElementById('pauseRecord').addEventListener('click', pauseRecording);
        document.getElementById('stopRecord').addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
        document.getElementById('playRecording').addEventListener('click', playRecording);
        document.getElementById('popChunk').addEventListener('click', popLastChunk);

        function startRecording() {
            if (!recording) {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
                    .then(stream => {
                        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                            if (event.data.size > 0) {
                                chunks.push(event.data);
                                console.log("Chunk recorded: ", event.data.size, " bytes");
                            }
                        };

                        mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                            recreateBlob();
                        };

                        mediaRecorder.start();
                        recording = true;
                        console.log("MediaRecorder started");

                        document.getElementById('startRecord').innerText = 'Resume Recording';
                        document.getElementById('pauseRecord').disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById('stopRecord').disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById('popChunk').disabled = false;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error("getUserMedia error:", error);
                    });
            } else {
                mediaRecorder.resume();
                console.log("MediaRecorder resumed");

                document.getElementById('pauseRecord').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('startRecord').disabled = true;
            }
        }

        function pauseRecording() {
            mediaRecorder.pause();
            console.log("MediaRecorder paused");
            mediaRecorder.requestData(); //Raise a dataavailable event
            document.getElementById('startRecord').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('pauseRecord').disabled = true;
        }

        function stopRecording() {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            console.log("MediaRecorder stopped");

            document.getElementById('stopRecord').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('playRecording').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('pauseRecord').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('startRecord').disabled = true;
        }

        function recreateBlob() {
            const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: mediaRecorder.mimeType });
            audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log("Recreated blob URL:", audioURL);

            document.getElementById('audioPlayback').src = audioURL;
        }

        function playRecording() {
            const audio = document.getElementById('audioPlayback');
            audio.play();
            console.log("Playing recording");
        }

        function popLastChunk() {
            if (chunks.length > 0) {
                chunks.pop();
                console.log("Last chunk removed. Remaining chunks:", chunks.length);
                recreateBlob();
            } else {
                console.warn("No chunks to pop.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>



